How do I do SSE load testing with Node Js?
I have such a code and I want to do a load test on it to see how many open connections it can handle at the same time. How can I do this?
app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    res.flushHeaders(); 

    const clientId = uuidv4(); 
    const newClient = {
        id: clientId,
        res,
    };
    clients.push(newClient);
    console.log(`New client connected: ${clientId}. Total clients: ${clients.length}`);

    req.on('close', () => {
        console.log(`Client ${clientId} closed connection. Worker ${process.pid}`);
        clients = clients.filter((client) => client.id !== clientId);
    });

    if (currentData) {
        res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(currentData)}\n\n`);
    }
});


Why dont you try wrk benchmarking tool or k6.

Could you recommend me a resource where I can do the SSE test with k6, I am very new to these topics and I couldn't find any.
